# html() returning undefined on coworkers computer

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, dom

I have some content on a page that I'm replacing on document ready.
This works fine on all browsers on my computer.

For my coworker though, (in chrome for sure, and I think in firefox), it works, but then if he navigates away and comes back, the console log entries below show 'undefined'; even though that div contains a default string in the page's html.

Any idea what would cause this? Could security settings or an ad blocker or something do this? Super confused!

**Default HTML (Contains shopify sections that I don't believe to be relevant to the issue)**

```
<div class="Container">
    <link type="text/css" href="xxx" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        div.dealerPageContent { margin:50px 0px 50px 0px; }
        .fxrui-grid { padding:0px; }
    </style>
    <div class="PageContent">
        {%- section 'slideshow-dealer' -%}
        <div class="dealerPageContent">Your dealer's information should appear here. If you're not seeing anything, please get in touch on our <a href="/contact">contact page</a>.</div>
        {{ page.content }}<!---this is blank--->
        {%- section 'tiles-ui-dealer1' -%}
        {%- section 'tiles-ui-dealer2' -%}
    </div>
</div>
```

**The content replace function as it currently exists**

```
function doDealerReplacements(){
    if(typeof customerDealerHtml !=='undefined'){
      $("<div style='width:100%; background-color:#efefef; text-align:center; padding:8px; border-bottom:1px solid black;'><a href='/pages/dealer'><img style='height:44px; width:auto; border:0px;' src='"+customerDealerLogo+"'></a></div>").insertBefore('div#shopify-section-header');
      console.log('DEALER CHANGES: added logo, now will hide other bar');
      $("div#shopify-section-announcement").hide();
      console.log('DEALER CHANGES: bar hidden; now will do scroll fix');
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      console.log('DEALER CHANGES: scroll fix done; now will insert html');
      console.log('div.dealerPageContent current content is:');
      console.log($( "div.dealerPageContent" ).html());
      $( "div.dealerPageContent" ).html( customerDealerHtml );
    }
    else console.log('dealer info not set!');
    
  }
```

for extra context, he also gets a few errors that I don't. Having trouble tracking where these requests originate, but weird that he gets them and I don't. Sorry, all I have is his screen shot at the moment: [failed to load resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw4gz.png)

Comment: Has your coworker tried hard refreshing the page in case its been cached? I belive Ctrl+F5 will hard refresh in Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: Are you using ajax to load any of that content?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The Connection Reset error is shown when the browser cannot gather all details from the web server due to the connection being closed or reset by the server. You state the content is loading locally, so I suspect a resource is not readable or is being changed; such that it's path is no longer the same. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example:

Comment: @VividlyFaded - I believe this does fix it for him, but it returns to the unwanted state when he comes back.

Comment: @charlietfl - Originally, yes; but at this point it's just stored in a cookie and the ajax should not be happening at all.

Comment: @Twisty those connection reset errors are actually unrelated to when I'm doing. I just find it odd that he gets them and I don't. For the example you're requesting, you mean just host a page somewhere containing only the relevant code?

Comment: Suspect there's something you aren't telling us about what's undefined. `html()` won't return that. Is it `$` undefined perhaps or somthing like that?

Comment: @teezeCrost No, either edit your post and include a snippet or review the article I posted for other methods.

Comment: @charlietfl Here are screen shots of what I'm logging to the console, and the results. Again, because the results came from a different computer I cannot provide the text.
https://ibb.co/Y492BWx
https://ibb.co/BNhjMjQ

Comment: @Twisty I've broadened the code offered in the original post. I hope this helps.